# Activity is automatically going back after completion timer

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a fitness app and I have added a timer and a ringtone which is supposed to ring after completion of the timer. However, when the timer ends, it does not ring and the whole activity goes back automatically to its previous state (list of all workouts). Here is my code

```
countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(60 * 1000, 1000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        String text = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d : %02d",
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) % 60,
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) % 60);
        time.setText(text);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        mediaPlayer.start();
        time.setText("01 : 00");
        String txt = "Workout Completed";
        nextWorkout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Toast.makeText(context, txt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
};
countDownTimer.start();
```

Media player code

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.alarm);
```

Comment: how the code for your `mediaplayer`? probably the problem come from that..Please attach your `mediaplayer` as well

Comment: If you are able to see the Toast message then there is nothing wrong with the counter. Did you check the ring tone, without the counter?

Comment: No Toast is not appearing

Comment: Oh silly mistake, I was giving wrong context in Toast.  Now It's working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you have given the wrong context of Toast.

```
Toast.makeText(context, txt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Here is the problem. Check the context here.